# What is going to happen if you place a pitot tube on a working syphon?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

I was trying to understand the pressure difference across 2 points on a working syphon and came across this youtube video:
https://youtu.be/ofoR4Sgk1b8.

Previously i thought that at any point on a working syphon there would be either pressure due to atmosphere(Patm) or pressure due to the weight of the fluid above(ρgh) or both.Am I wrong on this?
In the above video,what causes pressure A and B ?

Is the fluid on the syphon pressurized like running fluid on a pipe?

If so, then placing a pitot tube to measure that pressure would be possible

I can understand the pressure difference between points C and D but i don't understand the pressure difference between points A and B.

Thank you for spending time on my question 
[image]